# python requests sending None instead of null

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, locust

I've looked around but was unable to find any information that clearly answers this.  I might be doing this wrong, but I'm sending a JSON in locustio using Python(3.6) (which uses Python requests library under the hood) that looks like:

```
{'Owner': None, 'Address': '123 sample', 'Introduction': 'hello', 'State': 1, 'Id': 1, 'EIN': '54330345', 'Name': 'company', 'Logo': None}

r=self.client.put("/usergroup/1",json=grp)
```

My question is does each None get converted to null before hitting the server side?  Does the requests library handle all of the conversions between null and None for sending/receiving ?

Comment: No, but the `json` module does.

Comment: If your client is using the `json` parameter then yes. But if it uses the `data` parameter, the `None` items are not included in the post data.